# Passing variables between React Components to initialize a rendering after an user login

Tags: reactjs

I have this in my **Login.tsx**

```
export const Login = () => {


    axios.post("login", login).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        localStorage.setItem('admin_auth', res.data.currentUser["admin_auth"]);
        localStorage.setItem('authorized', res.data.currentUser["authorized"]);
        localStorage.setItem('given_name', res.data.currentUser["given_name"]);
        setToken(res.data.token);
        navigate("/");
    });

return (

.. some Login Form HTML ..

}
```

So after a User logs in successfully, he will be navigated to "/", which is in my **App.tsx** -> **export default () => {...}** In this code I have a NavBar, which contains something like:

```
(authIsAuthorized == "true") ? authWelcomeMessageAuthorized : authWelcomeMessageUnauthorized}
```

If I refresh the website, the variable "authIsAuthorized" is true and the correct welcome message will be shown. **But it does not work for the "navigate("/")" after a successful login.** After the navigate, the "old" stuff is rendered and authIsAuthorized is false.

How can I make a connection between my **"Login"** and **"default App"** components to let my default App known that something has changed?

Comment: how do you check if its authorized? (whats in `authIsAuthorized`)?

Comment: maybe better, show us please your `App.tsx`

Comment: This is in the "authIsAuthorized": const authIsAuthorized = localStorage.getItem("authorized");

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useEffect` in your `App` component to see if it the user is logged in or not.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(authIsAuthorized) {
    authWelcomeMessageAuthorized
  } else {
    authWelcomeMessageUnauthorized
  }
}, [authIsAuthorized])
```

This `useEffect` function will run when the page renders and it will also run when the value of `authIsAuthorized` changes.

Comment: Hi Dharmik, I tried this piece of code with an alert. It looks like it does not have any effect, after I navigate to "/". from Login.tsx. The piece of code does not get called (I tried it with alerts wether the user is logged in or not) - But this works If I log-out on the same page ("/").